# Perforce Checkpoint Notification

Tags: perforce

We have a job scheduled in crontab that does create a nightly checkpoint; however, we want to notify a DL or group as soon as a new checkpoint file, "p4_1.ckp.XXXX.gz," is added under "/p4/1/checkpoints."

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Perforce doesn't have any built in notification mechanism, but it sounds like it should be as simple as adding a notification as the last step in the script that your cronjob kicks off.  How exactly you do that depends on the type of the notification, but as long as it's something with a CLI (or a web API that you can easily kick off via `curl` or similar) it should be easy to add to a script.